# Unable to update PowerShell with "couldn't complete the updates undoing changes" error

Tags: windows, powershell, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 instance running on Hyper-V that I'm attempting to update from PowerShell 4.0 to PowerShell 5.1. Once the update has been applied, I reboot the server to apply the updates and immediately afterwards,  Windows displays:

> We couldn't complete the updates
>
> Undoing Changes
>
> Don't turn off your computer

Researching online has led me to believe that it is an issue with the Secure-Boot option in Hyper-V. When I attempt to edit this option in Powershell:

```
Set-VMFirmware "Build Server" -EnableSecureBoot Off
```

I am given the error:

> Set-VMFirmware : A parameter is invalid. Generation 1 virtual machines
>   do not support the VMFirmware cmdlets

How can I find the root cause of this issue, and if disabling the Secure-Boot in Hyper-V is the solution, how can I do this on a Gen1 VM?

EDIT: After attempting to update Windows with the latest patches, I received the same "couldn't complete the updates Undoing changes" message. This seems to be a problem with the windows update, and not PowerShell specifically...

Comment: Gen1 VMs don’t use secure boot.  So that probably isn’t your problem.  Is .NET the correct version?  WMF/Powershell requires a certain version of .NET that the system might not have if you haven’t already applied all updates.

Comment: I am running .NET 4.6.1. It looks like Powershell 5.0 requires .NET 4.5, so I don't think that's the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few hours of researching, it appears that the issue was **not** due to the Secure-Boot on the VM, but was instead because of the **contents/volume of the Windows Temp directory**. This appears to be an issue in Azure Windows VMs as well. The *C:\Windows\Temp* directory on my VM was ~2.8gb. The steps I followed were:

1. Remove any handles on  *C:\Windows\Temp*
2. Delete *C:\Windows\Temp*
3. Run *Windows Update*
4. Restart Virtual Machine
5. Run the Windows Server 2012 R2 *Windows Mangement Framework 5.1* installer
6. Restart Virtual Machine

Note: Some sources suggested setting the *TEMP* environment variable to point to C:\Windows\Temp directly if it already does not. My TEMP variable points to the administrator account's temp directory. I did **not** change this when following the steps above. In this case, it did not appear to make a difference.